# I am not able to make a POST request in swift

Tags: ios, swift, post

I am unable to make a successful POST request in swift. It shows an the following
`error`"kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9847`,`NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://192.168.1.167:8100/Attendance/login,"`.`

It worked perfectly with my older version of swift. Now I have updated my Xcode and this issue occurred.

```
func logSetRequest(){
        let urlString = "https://192.168.1.167:8100/Attendance/login"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        theRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let parameters = [ "email": usernameTxtField.text!,"password": passwordTxtField.text!] as Dictionary<String, String>
        var err: NSError?

        do {
            theRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            theRequest.HTTPBody = nil
        } // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

        theRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        var connectRequest  = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest, delegate: self)
        logActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
```

I have made relevant changes in plist also

Answer (score 0):

From googling it seems that error code `-9847` has something to do with SSLHandshake failing.

You said that you've upgraded to a new version of Swift. In iOS 9.0/OS X 10.11 Apple introduced App Transport Security, which requires you to run `HTTPS`, which you also do. But maybe there is something wrong with the `HTTPS` setup that worked before, but has stopped working under iOS 9.

You can read more about ATS (and how to *temporarily* disable it) here:

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Hope that helps